# how to select a Div ID that does not have a specifc class/es

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am working on a web application, and i have a div with ID = `WebPartWPQ2` .I define the following css rule to define its min-width:-

```
#WebPartWPQ2  {
    min-width:1280px;
}
```

currently this will apply to all the Divs that have this ID. but currently i have the following div :-

```
<div id="WebPartWPQ2" class="ms-wpContentDivSpace " style="" allowexport="false" allowdelete="false" allowremove="false" width="100%" haspers="false" webpartid2="e5a46e55-7c76-4d8c-be2c-e3022b7080fc" webpartid="e8865b18-0e92-4276-9945-9091e47e7b0f">
```

which have the associated ID and a class named "ms-wpcontentDivSpace" , so how i can exclude this Dic that have this class from my above  css rule ?

Comment: Try `#id:not(.class)` note: id should be unique

Comment: Don't use multiple ID's on the same HTML page.

Comment: @makshh those are on different pages

Comment: @Akshay seems using "#id:not(.class)" will work in my case, but can you aidvce please on its browser support ? is it supported by IE,firefox, chrome & safari ?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 IE9+ (IE6-8 will work with selevtivzr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#WebPartWPQ2.ms-wpContentDivSpace {
    min-width: 0; /*fallback*/
    min-width: initial;
}
```

You could also change your declaration to this:

```
#WebPartWPQ2:not(.ms-wpContentDivSpace) {
    min-width:1280px;
}
```

I personally think the first one is easier to read.

Comment: It doesn't have the greatest browser support though. So far only WebKit/Blink derivatives support it and Firefox supports it prefixed. That's it. For once, `:not()` actually has excellent browser support by current standards. That being said, you could easily replace the initial keyword with the actual initial value, zero, then all these browser support issues go away.

Comment: @BoltClock so are toy saying that initial; does not have a great browser support ?

Comment: @Carson now using 'id:not(.class) will work for me,, but can you adivce about its browser support ? i mean is it supported by IE,Chrome,Firefox & safari ??

Comment: @johnG the first one should work just as well with the added fallback. Its up to you which to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, it is not right to have several elements in the same document sharing the same ID. If you decide to give an ID to an element, it must be *unique*.

If you want to differenciate groups of elements, *classes* are intended for that.

Comment: those are not on the same screen ,, those are on separate screens. this is a third part app so i have no control over the html ,, but i can define custom css to override the defualt style ...

Answer (score 0):

ID stands for identifier, which means that it must be unique. Use class instead of id, if you intend to use the same rule at more tags at the same page and do not duplicate ids.

```
.WebPartWPQ2:not(.exception)  {
    min-width:1280px;
}

<div class="ms-wpContentDivSpace WebPartWPQ2 exception" style="" allowexport="false" allowdelete="false" allowremove="false" width="100%" haspers="false" webpartid2="e5a46e55-7c76-4d8c-be2c-e3022b7080fc" webpartid="e8865b18-0e92-4276-9945-9091e47e7b0f">
```

Comment: this is a third part app so i have no control over the html ,, but i can define custom css to override the defualt style ...

Answer (score 0):

the `:not()` selector would be useful, as others have already mentioned. It has good support in modern browsers, but not IE8.

If you needed an IE8-friendly solution,first declare the rule that is true *most* of the time:

```
#WebPartWPQ2  {
    min-width:1280px;
}
```

Then declare a rule that overrides the first with a higher specificity:

```
#WebPartWPQ2.ms-wpContentDivSpace {
    min-width: initial;
}
```